# Topology of the "normal spectrum" of a commutative von Neumann algebra

Tags: von-neumann-algebras, gn.general-topology

Kadison and Ringrose define normal states $\omega$ of a von Neumann algebra $A$ as such that $\omega(H_\alpha)\to \omega(H)$ for each monotone increasing net of operators $H_\alpha$ with least upper bound $H$ (definition 7.1.11)

Let $A$ be a commutative von Neumann algebra and $NS(A)$ be its set of normal characters, and let us endow $NS(A)$ by some natural topology, for example, by the the weak topology generated by elements of $A$. 
Did anybody try to describe the topological properties of $NS(A)$? As far as I understand, usually this space is not compact, but from the construction of the von Neumann envelope it follows that such spaces are "natural covers" for all Hausdorff compact spaces. So I wonder how this picture can be explained from the topological point of view.

Comment: For $A=L^\infty[0,1]$ don't you get that $NS(A)$ is empty?

Comment: Yes, I have corrected: USUALLY NS(A) is not compact. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If by a normal character you mean a normal morphism of C*-algebras A→**C**,
then every commutative von Neumann algebra canonically decomposes
as a product of its atomic and diffuse parts,
the atomic part canonically decomposes as a product ∏<sub>i∈I</sub>**C**,
and the set of normal characters is canonically isomorphic to I.
In geometric terms, every measurable space is a disjoint union of its atomic and diffuse parts,
and the atomic part is a disjoint union of points, which can be identified with the normal characters of A.
The only natural topology on the set of normal characters is the discrete topology,
in particular the weak topology induced by A is discrete.

To answer the other question, if we take all characters (not necessarily normal),
i.e., the spectrum of the underlying C*-algebra, then the resulting space is hyperstonean.
Furthermore, for the von Neumann envelope of a commutative C*-algebra A
the resulting map of compact Hausdorff spaces C*-Spec(W*-env(A))→C*-Spec(A)
is the hyperstonean cover of C*-Spec(A).

Alternatively, one can invoke the [Gelfand-Neumark theorem for commutative von Neumann algebras](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/measurable+locale),
which states in particular that the opposite category of the category of commutative
von Neumann algebras is equivalent to the category of measurable locales,
which in its turn embeds fully faithfully in the category of locales, which is very
similar to the category of topological spaces (and contains Hausdorff topological
spaces as a full subcategory).
Thus the spectrum of a commutative von Neumann algebra is a locale,
and bounded functions on this locale are precisely the elements of the original
commutative von Neumann algebra.
Of course, the argument above proves that the interesting part of this locale
(the one that corresponds to the diffuse part of the original von Neumann algebra)
has no points (but it is highly nontrivial anyway), in particular it is nonspatial,
i.e., does not come from a topological space and thus provides
an example of a pointfree / pointless topological space.
Arguably this fact can be seen as yet another argument for replacing
topological spaces by locales in mathematics.

Comment: "If by a normal character you mean a normal morphism of C*-algebras" -- yes, of course. Discrete topology? So the topological explanation is trivial... That is interesting. But where is it written? By the way, in your link I did not find a mentioning of Gelfand-Neumark.

Comment: The facts mentioned in the first two paragraphs one can find in Takesaki's Theory of Operator Algebras I, in particular Section III.1.  The Gelfand-Neumark theorem for commutative von Neumann algebras is discussed in the last two paragraphs of the “Definitions” section in the link above.

Comment: Dima, apparently, I am doing something wrong, but I can't understand the text in your link because of the abundance of phrases "Math Processing Error". What should I do to look at the formulas?

Comment: Dima, and where does Takesaki prove this: "The only natural topology on the set of normal characters is the discrete topology, in particular the weak topology induced by A is discrete."

Comment: @Sergei: At the bottom of the page you can find a link to the TeX source.  Every normal character is an isolated point in the weak topology, because the preimage of the open set (0,2) with respect to the evaluation at the characterstic function of the corresponding point is an open singleton.

Comment: @Dmitri Pavlov: > Every normal character is an isolated point in the weak topology, > because the preimage of the open set (0,2) with respect to the > evaluation at the characterstic function of the corresponding > point is an open singleton. Stylistically it would be more precise to say: "...because the preimage of an open set under the action of a continuous function is always an open set". A question: why does this characteristic function exist?

Comment: @Sergei: I fail to see how your statement is more precise than mine.  An open singleton is an open set, but not every open set is an open singleton.  I also don't understand the question about the existence of the characteristic function.

Comment: @Dmitri: That is irony: your explanation is so vague that it is equivalent (as an explanation) to a phrase like "everything follows from the fact that the preimage of a continuous map preserves open sets". Moreover, stylistically the last phrase is more preferable, since it better expresses the aroma of absurd. :) However, Julia Kuznetsova has already gave me an exact reference, namely, Corollary 1.13 in Takesaki's chapter III. So if you don't mind, I will thank her for this.

Comment: @Sergei: I gave you a reference to §III.1 in Takesaki's book in my first comment.  Corollary III.1.13 is clearly an overkill in this case.

Comment: @Dmitri: Takesaki's III.1 is 18 pages long. In addition, the text is quite difficult for non-specialists, and one should be quite sophisticated in those tricks to see that Corollary 1.13 indeed implies what I need. For 2 days I was trying to understand your hints, and finally I had to ask another specialist, Julia Kuznetsova. Only after her explanations I understood what one can have in mind here. My opinion is that each work, including helping people, can be done punctually and agreeably for those who need help. Or carelessly and disagreeably for them. And it is Julia who did it punctually.

Comment: @Sergei: Instead of asking specific questions about the parts of the proof that are unclear to you, you immediately started to complain ("Stylistically it would be more precise to say...").  I cannot but remark that such nonconstructive position can hardly help you to achieve your goals.  Comments on MathOverflow are not expected to be as precise as refereed papers.  Some vagueness is always expected, and you are expected to ask further questions if something is unclear to you, instead of complaining and attempting to ridicule those who are trying to help you.

Comment: @Sergei: Here is an alternative description of the same proof: The von Neumann algebra under consideration can be assumed to be atomic (normal characters only see the atomic part), i.e., isomorphic to the algebra of bounded functions on some set S.  Its predual can be identified with L^1(S).  The topological space of normal characters is the subspace of L^1(S) consisting of those elements of L^1(S) that take value 1 on some element on S and vanish elsewhere.  The L^1-distance between any two such elements is 2, hence the topology is discrete.

Comment: @Dmitry: That was not a complaint, that was irony, I told this alredy. But if you want to continue this discussion, you can open a topic in Meta (in November you told me about this possibility http://mathoverflow.net/questions/80146/is-the-mendeleev-table-explained-in-quantum-mechanics , I hope, you remember this), and I promise to explain there what is still not clear. There must be judges in our dispute, otherwise it would be unsolvable.

Comment: @Sergei: Meta is not an appropriate venue for clarifying answers (read the faq to get an idea about the purpose of the meta); such clarifications (and requests for them) belong here in the comments.  This is not a discussion nor a dispute; the very fact that you seem to think otherwise indicates a problem with your attitude.

Comment: This is like a dialogue between people who don't understand interlocutor's langauge. Dima, after Julia's explanation I don't need further clarifications, she clarified everything (by the way, that is why what you wrote about L^1(S) was extra). My suggestion was that if you didn't understand what I find to be wrong in your answer here, then we can discuss this in meta, like I already did once after your suggestion: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1202/should-a-mathematician-be-a-robot/#Item_0 This won't be mathematics, this is ethics, so don't tell me again that this is not for meta.