# What is the status of the Born Rule in axiomatic QM?

Tags: pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics, it.information-theory, quantum-mechanics, axioms

While physicists have tried multiple times and failed to derive the [Born Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule) (for example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0409144.pdf). I was wondering what axiomatic Quantum Mechanics had to say about this? Is it fundamentally impossible to derive the Born Rule or is there hope?

Here's a link of great discussion in the same spirit:
https://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/wordpress/?p=10533&cpage=1

In fact here we have someone summarising good reasons/books to believe that it indeed may be possible:  http://www.johnboccio.com/research/quantum/notes/bell.pdf

I suspect Lubos Motl was something of the opinion the measurement that should be a separate fundamental axiom. If so, I suspect it becomes a problem of showing: there is no non-redundant axiom when the Born Rule is included?
https://motls.blogspot.com/2018/09/woit-and-probability-in-quantum.html

Comment: Is there axiomatic quantum mechanics?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov there is  Dirac–von Neumann axioms but I suspect there would be other reformulations too by now ...

Comment: here is one recent attempt to derive the Born rule axiomatically: [The measurement postulates of quantum mechanics are operationally redundant](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.11060)

Comment: More Anonymous, it's an exaggeration to say that the Dirac–von Neumann "axioms" give an axiomatization of quantum mechanics: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80146/is-the-mendeleev-table-explained-in-quantum-mechanics

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov while what you reference does make it plausible that these axioms are insufficient ... Going from the "rule-book" (axioms) to the "play book" (the real world) takes effort, time and ingenuity ... Game of life is an easy example and still is the topic many people's thesis's

Comment: Anonymous, this "play book" too much resembles cheating. So that it's impossible to find differences.

Comment: There is a topic called [reconstruction of quantum mechanics](https://www.quantumfoundations.org/reconstruction-of-quantum-mechanics.html) that tries to do stuff like what you are asking.  I'll leave it to you to judge its status.